# How do I use this mixin to alter the DateTime object?

Tags: ruby

I need to alter the DateTime object. The resource I've found states that this is what I need to do, but I'm not sure exactly what to do with this code. Where do I put it? Thanks for reading.

```
module DateTimePatch
    def getlocal
        "works!"
    end
end

DateTime.send(:include, DateTimePatch)
```

EDIT:
So this is what I have

/lib/date_time.rb

```
class DateTime
  def getlocal
    "it works"
  end
end
```

Console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Time.now.getlocal
=> 2010-11-09 23:40:36 +1000
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > DateTime.now
 => Tue, 09 Nov 2010 23:40:57 +1000 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > DateTime.now.getlocal
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for Tue, 09 Nov 2010 23:41:02 +1000:DateTime
```

EDIT2:

Ok so now I'm doing:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require './lib/date_time.rb'
=> true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > DateTime.now.getlocal
NoMethodError: undefined method `now' for DateTime:Class
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/benhartney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > DateTime.now
NoMethodError: undefined method `now' for DateTime:Class
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/benhartney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

I tried adding a temporary `now` method to the mixin to see if the error still occurred and it did. DateTime.now worked fine before I loaded the mixin, not sure why this is happening?

Comment: What is the resource you're referring to?

Comment: Also, try the `send!` method instead of `send`. Any errors?

Comment: Are you executing `/lib/date_time.rb` at all?

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to add a method to the `DateTime` class ? Try:

```
class DateTime
  def get_local
    "works!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do I put that file? In lib? And where do I run the DateTime.send(:include, DateTimePatch) line?

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the "send". Put the file in the lib folder and it should work.

Comment: Does this work if the get_local method already exists? i.e. will it override DateTime's definition?

Comment: Couldn't get it working, I've edited the results into the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you forgot to `require` your file.

```
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.now.getlocal
NoMethodError: undefined method `getlocal' for #
        from (irb):2
        from d:/Ruby/bin/irb.bat:20:in `'
irb(main):003:0> require './lib/date_time.rb'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> DateTime.now.getlocal
=> "it works"
```

UPD: and `require 'date'` in order to use ruby's `DateTime` class.

Comment: Yep adding require 'date' will work for your second edit ben.